# Export from Oracle to MongoDB using python

Tags: python, oracle, mongodb

I know there are various ETL tools available to export data from oracle to MongoDB but i wish to use python as intermediate to perform this. Please can anyone guide me how to proceed with this?
Requirement:
Initially i want to add all the records from oracle to mongoDB and after that I want to insert only newly inserted records from Oracle into MongoDB.

Appreciate any kind of help.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question directly:
 1. Connect to Oracle
 2. Fetch all the delta data by timestamp or id (first time is all records)
 3. Transform the data to json
 4. Write the json to mongo with pymongo
 5. Save the maximum timestamp / id for next iteration

Keep in mind that you should think about the data model considerations and usually relational DB (like Oracle) and document DB (like mongo) will have different data model.